# How can I force cups to send only black and white to my monochrome printer

Tags: printing, cups

How can I force cups to send only black and white to my monochrome printer? By black here, I mean anything not white; that's to say, no grey scale. There are answers here about enforcing grey scale on colour printers, but I want only 100% or 100% white on the output. The reason for this is that sometimes, with my poor eyesight, I cannot read things printed at, say, 30% black.

Comment: Did you mean you want the contrast to be higher when printed?

Comment: What is your printer model and the OS?

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing yes. Ideally the contrast should be 100%.

The OS is Linux and the printer is Brother HL-2250DN.

Comment: Does anyone have anything new on this?  This is a big problem when dealing with people who insist on sending color documents.